# Is it bad practice or a bad idea to have a "generic" provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, testing, provisioning

Fot testing iPhone apps, is it a bad idea to have a *development* code signing provision that will run any app with com.mydomain.* ?

Why?

EDIT:

See italicized edit above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you talking about the development or distribution code signing provision?

I use a generic code signing provision for development (otherwise it would be absurd to run any sample code from online, or test apps).

For distribution though, I get a unique identifier. I sort of assumed it was required. Just for safety's sake.

Comment: I'm talking about the development provisions. 

For distribution, I am going to venture to say that unique provisions are best. Unique provisions are required for push and in-app purchases.

Comment: Even during development you are going to want to test push notifications, so a unique identifier is advisable there too as the extra effort to generate the profile is minimal.

Comment: @Cirrostratus - true. I don't add push to all of my apps though.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt it, the provisioning profile is specific to a set of UUIDs.  No one else would be able to use the profile unless they had your developer certificate and the specific device.

However, you can't test push notifications nor in-app purchases with a generic profile.